# Is there a way to get a permanent link (permalink) to the current version of a DokuWiki page?

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

Is there a way to generate a permanent link to the current version of a page? I can get a link to previous versions (for example https://www.dokuwiki.org/faq:support?rev=1354115567) by clicking Old Revisions.

Answer (score 1):

Using `?rev=0` in the URL will always take you to the current revision at the time. Maybe a null-edit would help (the content doesn't change and you *may* get a edit history entry).

Now, if you have actual access to the fileserver where your DW is hosted, you can fetch the `id` of the most recent revision (the at-the-moment-current-one) by first checking the id of the latest edit in Old Revisions, then going to the `${DOKUWIKI}/data/attic` directory and checking the numbers that correspond to the pagename that you want. There will be one file with a more recent `id` (a higher numeric value) which, if I'm not mistaken, corresponds to the current revision. For example, for a last edit of `mypage.1263571254.txt.gz` you might find **one** higher index of, say, `mypage.1291408231.txt.gz`.

**EDIT**: the same value does show somewhere in the rendered page's source. If you have section editing enabled and the buttons do show up in the page, search the source (CTRL+U on most browsers) for `form class="button btn_secedit"`, then continue reading until you read an input element with `name="rev"` and a `value=` that should correspond to the number of the current revision.

---

Using that found `id` as the argument of `?rev=` should reveal if it is the correct one and as a result get you the permalink to this revision.

**Note**: I have not tried this in my own install.